# How can a function print variable name along with value stored in it in cpp?

Tags: c++

I have been using this piece of code from quite some time but honestly don't know how it exactly works. Detailed explanation or any blog links to understand this would be much appreciated.

```
#define bug(...) __f (#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__) 
template <typename Arg1>
void __f (const char* name, Arg1&& arg1){
    cout << name << " : " << arg1 << '\n'; 
}
template <typename Arg1, typename... Args>
void __f (const char* names, Arg1&& arg1, Args&&... args){
    const char* comma = strchr (names + 1, ',');
    cout.write (names, comma - names) << " : " << arg1 << " | "; __f (comma + 1, args...);
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why the tag [tag:cp], Unix copy command is used?

Comment: The identifier "__f" is reserved for the implementation. Don't use reserved names.

Comment: Observe that `bug(a,b,c)` expands to `__f("a,b,c",a,b,c)`, then follow the recursive template.